# GScript If/Then Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-sheets

Can anyone help me.  I have a moderate amount of experience in javascript but for the life of my I can not figure this out.  This code is transferring data from one sheet to another in a series of other functions being run.  I have limited it to just this function to troubleshoot the problem, so I know its not any other code I have written.

Here is my code:

```
if (school == 'PE') {
var admin_sheet = ss.getSheets()[3];}

else if (school == 'Archive') {
var admin_sheet = ss.getSheets()[2];}

else if (school =='Notify') {
var admin_sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];}

var lastRow = admin_sheet.getLastRow()+1;
var lCol = admin_sheet.getLastColumn();
```

It works the best if it is written to not compare both sides:

```
if (school = 'PE') {
var admin_sheet = ss.getSheets()[3];}

else if (school = 'Archive') {
var admin_sheet = ss.getSheets()[2];}

else if (school ='Notify') {
var admin_sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];}

var lastRow = admin_sheet.getLastRow()+1;
var lCol = admin_sheet.getLastColumn();
```

The problem is it is not reliable.  Here is the log

```
[20-06-08 09:09:15:563 PDT] Jonathan Smith
[20-06-08 09:09:15:564 PDT] Grade 11
[20-06-08 09:09:15:566 PDT] 253426
[20-06-08 09:09:15:568 PDT] Archive
```

When it transfers it to the new sheet it is not on the Archive Sheet but the Pre-Enrolled sheet and it lists the school as PE (Pre-Enrolled).  It is obviously pulling the data correctly as the correct school is listed as Archive, and I can't understand it placing it on the Pre-Enrolled sheet but how is it changing the variable it is pulling from Archive (as listed in the log) to Pre-Enrolled which is being written in the sheet?

I have written alot of If/Then else code before and have never had this issue so I am sure it is something I am missing, but I just can't seem to figure it out!

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: `=` is **assignment**, not comparison. Use `==` or `===`.

Comment: I have used == and === and it won't work.  Even with the == it still changes the school variable.